# JSON to XML with multiple records

Tags: java, xml, json

I am newbie in JAVA and trying to convert JSON data format to XML for multiple records. The result is not a well defined XML structure.The below code is working fine when a single record of item exists.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item": {
                "ID": "79C675F752491945E1A",
                "Subject": "test1 ",
                "Sender": "user1",
                "Date": "2014-07-14 14:14:40",
                "DocumentClassID": "1",
                "Comment": "",                
            }
        },

        {
            "item": {
                "ID": "79C67761945E1A",
                "Subject": "test2",
                "Sender": "user2",
                "Date": "2014-07-14 14:14:40",
                "DocumentClassID": "1",
                "Comment": "",

            }
        }

    ]
}
```

===================Code Snippet=============================

```
public class ConvJsonXml extends AbstractTransformation {

    public void transform(TransformationInput in, TransformationOutput out) throws StreamTransformationException {

          try {
          String sourcexml = ""; String targetxml =""; String line ="";

          InputStream ins = in.getInputPayload().getInputStream();
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ins));
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
          sourcexml +=line+"\n"; 
          br.close();

          JSONObject o = new JSONObject(sourcexml);
          targetxml = org.json.XML.toString(o);
          out.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream().write(targetxml.getBytes());

          }
            catch (Exception e) {
                   throw new StreamTransformationException(e.getMessage());
          }
        }

}
```

Please suggest me to add code in the Try block so that the conversion provides a well uniform XML structure.

Regards..

Comment: What do you call a "well uniformed XML structure"? Is the generated XML invalid XML?

Comment: you can try to use GSON ,library provided by google it will give you same output as it.also if you want to make json mannualy you can use JSONObject,JsonElement and other classes or buffer reader to make json manually